# I cannot add more Categories to my menu

Tags: categories

I am using the theme Hemingway Rewritten. I added 8 categories by adding "uncategorized" and then changing the navigation label. But at the bottom the original still says "uncategorized" so my posts aren't going to the navigation label, the way I want them to. It let me add 3 actual categorize like "puppy mama" and then the original also says "puppy mama" so the post went to the correct spot. Not sure what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Category label doesn't change where the menu item goes, you need to actually add the category. You can't add a menu item for uncategorized and change it to an actual category.

Comment: How do I add a category then?  When i'm customizing my menu, they all say category next to them just like pages say pages and the posts say post.

Comment: On the Menus screen, on the left, there's a list of types of things you can add to menus. One of them is Categories. Click that to expand it. Inside you'll see a list of Most Used categories. Check the boxes next to the ones you want to add and click Add to Menu. You can use the tabs above the list to also view All categories, or search for specific ones to add.

Comment: the only way I can add to my menus is if on the front page  I go click on the customize next to themes and them click menus and then from that point, there is an add items button at the bottom. So i click on that and go to categories, but it won't let me add anymore, it just shows the 3 I already have plus an uncategorized option.  Is there another menu screen i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer for the questions on a different site. You have to have a post (also adding the category and tag within the post) before it will let you create the category page on the menu.